# How to make the variable public in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, public

I needed to find the vendornumber value to construct a matrix from the given data. I wrote the code (in VBA) below

(it has more rows for the matrix construction but i cut them here)

```
Public Sub tryout()
 Dim vendornumber As Integer
 Dim rownumber As Integer
 rownumber = Worksheets("DISTANCE").Range("A2", 
 Worksheets("DISTANCE").Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
    Dim y As Integer
    Do Until (y = rownumber)
       y = vendornumber * (vendornumber + 1)
       vendornumber = vendornumber + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

The code works perfectly but I want to use this value in other modules as well. I tried to make the variable public as:

```
Public vendornumber As Integer
```

It gave the error:

> Invalid attribute in Sub or Function.

Then, I put this row to out of the sub and it gave the error: *Overflow* and pointed the part of the code below as the reason:

`y = vendornumber * (vendornumber + 1)`

Comment: The Public line must be before your Sub line (at the top of the procedure).

Comment: if you want `vendornumber` to be public move `Dim vendornumber as Integer` outside of the sub.

Comment: are you trying to use `rownumber` to find the last row?  if so, change `rownumber as Integer` to `rownumber as Long` and to find the last row with data in Column A `rownumber = worksheet("DISTANCE").Cells("DISTANCE").Rows.Count,"A2").End(xlUp).Row`

Comment: `Integer` is a 16-bit signed integer type, making its maximum value 32,767. The overflow error is thrown when you try to assign it a value greater than or equal to 32,768. Declaring `y As Long` (a 32-bit signed integer type) should fix it. Rule of thumb, you never need to declare anything `As Integer`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to declare the variables outside.

```
Public vendornumber As Integer

Public Sub tryout()
   vendornumber = 1
```

Comment: Although if the variable is declared in an object module (Sheet, class, etc.), it will need to be accessed "through" the object. For example, if a variable (`TestVar`) is declared in the "ThisWorkbook" module, it will be accessed via `ThisWorkbook.TestVar`